# I'm trying to understand the "rep scasb byte [edi]" instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

In this statement, is the value pointed to by `edi` the one that compares byte by byte, with the value pointed to by `eax`?

`rep scasb byte [edi]`

Comment: _"the value pointed to by eax"_ There's no _pointed to by_ `eax` here. `SCASB` compares the value in `al` with the value located in memory at the address given by `edi`. I suggest that you get Intel's x86 manual, as it contains pretty thorough descriptions of all instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/scas:scasb:scasw:scasd and https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rep:repe:repz:repne:repnz.

**But note that `rep scasb` is not encodeable**.

With `scasb`, the two `rep` prefixes are **`repe` and `repne`**.  The prefix byte that means `rep` with `stos`/`movs` means `repe` with `scas` and `cmps`.

REPE keeps repeating while ECX!=0 and ZF==1.  i.e. repeat while equal.

`repne scasb` implements `memchr`: find the first occurrence (if any) in a fixed-size buffer.

`repe scasb` finds the first byte != AL, or stops at the limit set by ECX.  So it's a bit like `strspn`, but still for an explicit size buffer, not a zero terminated C-string.

Answer (score 1):

`rep` means repeat until `ecx` is 0. `scasb` means 'scan byte', i.e: compare `al` with the byte at memory location `edi`, increment `edi` and decrement `ecx`.
What this means in effect is that before this line is run `ecx` has been set to a value that dictates how many times the `rep` will run for and if the characters match the zero flag `ZF` (which is also used for determining equality, hence why `je` and `jz` are equivalent) will be set.